# Django: Popup message not showing using Bootbox

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootbox

I am trying to display a `Bootbox`, which uses bootstrap modals, and make it display with some defined messages that already shows up with the regular messages whenever some bootstrap buttons are clicked but no success so far.

This is the code I have implemented in my `base.html` file to show the messages without the popup:

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Now, I dont want to use that anymore and want to use the `Bootbox` library. This is how I have it implemented in my `javascript.html` file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/moment.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/transition.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/collapse.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-filestyle.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootbox.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.0.0.js' %}"></script>

<script>

       $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.btn').on('click', function(){
               bootbox.alert(message);
           });
       });

</script>
```

This is the code in `views.py` where the `message` is extracted:

```
class EpisodeActionView(ProductionRequiredMixin, RedirectView):
    pattern_name = 'podfunnel:dashboard'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        if self.podcast.is_expired():
            messages.warning(request, 'Your account is mark as expired. Please contact your account manager for '
                                      'renewal options.')
        else:

            if self.production.base_production_produced:
                if not self.production.asynch_publish_in_process:
                    # Publish
                    self.production.asynch_publish_in_process = True
                    self.production.save()
                    podfunnel_full_publish_production.delay(self.production)
                    messages.success(request, 'Production queued for Output and Publishing. Please check later')
                else:
                    messages.warning(request, 'Production was already queued for publishing but not yet ready. '
                                              'Please check later')
            elif not self.production.base_production_started:
                # Produce
                podfunnel_asynch_produce_production.delay(self.production)
                messages.success(request, 'Production queued for Auphonic processing. Please check later')
            else:
                # Update from Auphonic
                success, message = podfunnel_update_production_from_auphonic(self.production)
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS if success else messages.WARNING, message)

        return super(EpisodeActionView, self).get(request)
```

Would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

**----UPDATE----**

My `css.html`

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/navbar-static-top.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.custom.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/podfunnel_custom.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "charsleft_widget/css/charsleft.min.css" %}" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

Comment: jQuery needs to be loaded before almost everything else in your list. Also, Bootbox hasn't really been tested against jQuery 3, although I have yet to find any issues in the little bit of testing I've done.

Comment: @TiesonT Thanks for the reply so I place jQuery and Bootbox on the top but still getting nothing. Which type of jQuery would you recommend?

Comment: Bootbox goes after bootstrap.js. You can use whatever version of jQuery you want, just be aware that Bootbox hasn't been tested against 3.0. As long as you use Bootstrap 3.3.7 or better, it *should* work

Comment: Thanks but that also didn't work. I am using bootstrap 3.3.6. Is it necessary to update to 3.3.7? Just wanted to give it a try with another jQuery version but every link in their website let me only download version 3.0+. I tried to use Google's CDN `<script src="{% static 'ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>` but no success either.

Comment: Since you don't include it in your question: have you added the CSS as well? And yes, if you want to use jQuery 3, you have to update to Bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: You can find older versions at https://code.jquery.com

Comment: Yes, just added my css in the bottom part of the question. Updated everything (css and js) to 3.3.7 but still no result.

Comment: So, are you seeing error messages in the JavaScript console? For `bootbox.alert(message);`, where is `message` defined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125436/discussion-between-w-lpz-and-tieson-t).